# Unable to start cqlsh for cassandra. Getting connection error: AttributeError("\'module\' object has no attribute \'decompress\'",)',)})

Tags: python, cassandra, connection, cqlsh

I have fresh installation of cassandra 3.11.5 with ubuntu 16.04. Installation is complete without any errors. I can also get the nodetool status as:

```
pc-2@pc2-VirtualBox:~$ nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1 
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               
Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  318.24 KiB  256          100.0%            ef702df8- 
aaf1-4e98-b771-41d4e9bc1bcf  rack1
```

But when I try to start cqlsh, I get following error:

```
pc-2@pc2-VirtualBox:~$ cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', 
{'127.0.0.1': ProtocolError('Unexpected response during Connection 
setup: AttributeError("\'module\' object has no attribute 
\'decompress\'",)',)})
```

Already tried:
1. cqlsh 127.0.0.1
2. export CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=true
3. Installed python-snappy,
still getting same error.

Comment: Solved it! I think problem was with module conflict. Previously, I had installed LZ4 library for python. I uninstalled LZ4 and it's working now.